# Curve path doesn't work on outer edges

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I created a 3d road. My problem is that I use curve path to bend the road,
but the path only bends the inner edges. How can I make it bend the whole mesh? I tried to follow videos to solve it, but all failed and my English is not that great. I used a translator. I hope some one can explain why this happens.

[image]

Comment: You don´t have enough divisions. You need to add more divisions in the road for it to bend properly